# How to configure .htaccess to limit access for webpage?

Tags: .htaccess

I have website at phys_server1 (domain A) and **payment.Gateway at phys_server2 (domain B).**

It is payment link (domainB/pay-here.php) at domainB (payment.Gateway).

I have to open access to webpage domainB/pay-here.php ONLY for visitors who arrive by link from domainA (domainA). DomainB also has other pages   which should be open without any restrictions.

How can I configure it?

Comment: I hope you are planning another layer of protection other than this. Anyone can fake a Referer header trivially.

Answer (score 0):

What about this : 
On your domainB server, on the .htaccess

```
Deny From All
Allow From https://domainA.link
```

Comment: Internal Server Error

Comment: I suppose if we configure Allow From it will allow/deny for hostname. But it is not about hostname here.

Comment: Can you make `ls -l` on your .htaccess ? TO be sure that your server could read this file. Have you activated mod_rewrite if you're using apache ? If you have other errors, activate the development mode and you'll have a significant error instead of 500 error page.